How to implement continuous speech recognition in the background on iOS?
I'd like to develop an app which runs continuous speech recognition even after going into the background. I’m building an iOS app that uses continuous speech recognition. It works fine when the app is in the foreground, but I need it to keep recognizing speech when the app goes into the background. On Android, I’ve achieved this using a foreground service. However, I’m struggling to find a way to implement this functionality on iOS.
I know I can accomplish this using audio background mode and then process the audio but I am not sure if this workaround would get accepted into App Store because of the processing limitations while in the background.
Problem:
When the app goes into the background (e.g., user locks the screen or switches to another app), the SFSpeechRecognizer stops, and the app no longer captures speech. I want it to work continuously in the background, similar to how Siri or the Advanced Voice Mode in the ChatGPT iOS app does.
Question:
How can I keep speech recognition active while the app is in the background or is it even possible?
Thanks, Marek
